# tcpkill: write: Operation not permitted with subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, linux, unix, subprocess

I'm trying to kill a TCP connection from a Python script. tcpkill runs, but gives that message on any data transfer:

```
tcpkill: write: Operation not permitted
***.***.***.***:48868 > ***.***.***.***:6905: R 1868230658:1868230658(0) win 0
```

My Python code is:

```
    @staticmethod
    def kill_connection(ip, interface="eth0"):
        def tcp_kill(ip, interface):
            logging.info('Killing ' + ip + ' connection with tcpkill.')
            p = subprocess.Popen('/sbin/tcpkill -i ' + interface + ' -9 ip host ' + ip, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
            time.sleep(30)
            p.terminate()

        t = threading.Thread(target=tcp_kill, args=(ip, interface))
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()
```

I tried with 'shell' option is on/off, setting pre-execution function to os.setguid. No chances.

Running tcpkill manually works fine.

What is causing this, and how I can make it run correctly?

Comment: are you running the script as root ?

Comment: Yes, root runs the script

Comment: please try to run the tcpkill command "by hand", as root in your bash shell, and see if the result is the same

Comment: Running by hand is working perfectly, I forgot to add this information

Comment: hmm... don't really know, that's not obvious. Running on Linux or MacOS ?

Comment: Running CentOS 7 x64

Comment: What version of Python are you running, because subprocess is different in 2.7 and 3+

Comment: I think I found the problem at any rate.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to take your kill command and put it into an array rather then a string.

```
    @staticmethod
def kill_connection(ip, interface="eth0"):
    def tcp_kill(ip, interface):
        logging.info('Killing ' + ip + ' connection with tcpkill.')
        p = subprocess.Popen(['/sbin/tcpkill', '-i ', interface, '-9', 'ip', 'host', ip],
                             stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
        time.sleep(30)
        p.terminate()

    t = threading.Thread(target=tcp_kill, args=(ip, interface))
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
```